# I can't use sub-query in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

this is my code :

```
  let followers = await models.User.findAll({ 
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.in]: await models.Following.findAll({attributes: ['followerId'], where: { followingId: req.session.user.id }})
      }
    } 
  })
```

And i want to use this code to get access to users that followed someone. but i got an error when i trying to run it 
and here is the error

> Error: Invalid value Following

please help me what should i do to handle this .

Comment: check value of second query , probably its not directly an array

Comment: @farhadamjady yes it is not an array but what should i do to get an array ?

Comment: please share what you get from this query